# Upgrade from IIS 7.5 to IIS 8.5 breaks OData with Hawk Authentication?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7.5, odata, iis-8.5

I am having a great deal of trouble solving a problem I encountered after upgrading from IIS 7.5 to IIS 8.5.

I have two Web Applications. One MVC Application, and one Standalone Web API. They are communicating with OData and Hawk Authentication through a Data Service Layer.

After the upgrade, there is a breaking change in the way URL-s are treated/parsed/handled. And I cannot find out where in this whole mess it goes wrong.

The queries:

```
http://api/odata/Car?$filter=Name eq 'BMW'        - Works
http://api/odata/Car?$filter=contains(Name,'BMW') - Works
http://api/odata/Car?$filter=Id eq 1 and 1=1      - Works
http://api/odata/Car(1) - Does not work
```

It seems to me that parentheses in the URL is not working in IIS8.5, or is in some way parsed differently from IIS7.5. Perhaps within Thinktecture.IdentityModel

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a deeper problem in the package.

https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityModel/issues/79